# VSCode not catching a thrown exception?

Tags: c++

I'm still learning C++ and I'm trying to implement exception handling using a try-catch block.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib> //for exit
const int divide_flag(-1);
double divide(double x, double y){
  if(x==0) throw divide_flag;
  return y/x;
}
int main()
{
  double x{3.},y{4.};
  double result;
  try{
    result=divide(x,y);
    std::cout<<"y/x = "<<result<<std::endl;
    x=0;
    result=divide(x,y);
    std::cout<<"y/x = "<<result<<std::endl;
  }
  catch(int error_flag) {
    if(error_flag == divide_flag) {
      std::cerr<<"Error: divide by zero"<<std::endl;
      exit(error_flag);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The code compiles fine but when I run it the program aborts after the exception is thrown and does not enter the catch block. The only output I get is

```
y/x = 1.33333
Abort trap: 6
```

I'm compiling with g++ on Mac and I'm not sure why the catch block is never entered.

Comment: @churill Well, and that's caused by a never (unlikely) true condition: `if(x==0)`?

Comment: I don't think the floating point Q's answer this, since zero is a value where exact comparison will work.

Comment: Okey ... reopened

Comment: What compiler are you using? With gcc 9.3.0 I get your "Error: divide by zero" line.

Comment: `exit(error_flag);` should be `std::exit(error_flag);`.  The `<cstdlib>` may not necessarily have `exit` in the global namespace.  (It doesn't on my machine.)

Comment: Adding std::exit didn't work, and I'm using gcc 8